# Does OVER (PARTITION BY [index]) help speeding up the query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm wondering the processing speed of

`SELECT something OVER (PARTITION BY C1, C2, C3, C4) FROM SOMETABLE`

will be improved by creating an index of `C1, C2, C3, C4` on `SOMETABLE`

Thanks!

Comment: [Here is a blog on this](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/06/indexing-for-windowing-functions/) and from the same blog [discussion further](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/09/indexing-windowing-functions-vs/) and a [book by Itzik Ben-Gan](https://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-High-Performance-Functions-Developer-Reference/dp/0735658366/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1530031235&sr=8-3) if you want to go further. Short answer, **yes** indexes can help.

Comment: Just [race your horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). And note that simon should have bolded the word **CAN** - an index can but is not guaranteed to help.

Comment: @scsimon, thanks for the help!

Comment: @smor thanks for the clarification!